# Multiple H1B Petitions

Tags: usa, h1-visa

Can I Raise 2 H1B petitions for myself through 2 different employers? If yes, How does it affect my chances in the Lottery?

Comment: Can you please add your citizenship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are [independent and unrelated positions](http://www.murthy.com/2015/02/11/h1b-cap-season-reminder-multiple-h1b-filings-for-same-beneficiary/), then it should be OK.

However this may trigger some Requests for Evidence (RFEs) which lead to the employers discovering about each other and potentially voiding their offers to you.

Comment: What is an RFE?

Comment: @phoog "Request For Evidence" - when the USCIS has questions about your petition. For example "Hey dawg, you got hired at two places full time - which one you'll actually be working at, man?". RFEs go to the petitioner, which is the employer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  But shouldn't that be "yo dawg..."?

Comment: Yeah, probably, haven't been in Compton for like a decade already...